# Nginx geo ip module doesn't work, cannot find a way to debug

Tags: debugging, nginx, geoip

I follow nginx geoip configuration guide here http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-how-to-block-visitors-by-country-with-the-geoip-module-debian-ubuntu

I write something like this

```
geoip_country /path/to/GeoIP.dat;
```

I am pretty sure the .dat file is there, and nginx has permission to access it. However, the `geoip_country_code` variable seems not set.

I've tried many approaches to debug, like

```
add_header X-debug-message "$geoip_country_code";
```

or

```
log_format debug "$geoip_country_code"
```

for header, nginx returns empty result. And for log format, it simply record nothing. My bet is geoip_country_code is not even defined, so nginx cannot deal with it or what.

I tried to read the server error log, however, nothing there (nothing about geoip and the undefined variable). It's kinda annoying, how can I know what's going on with nginx and the geoip module?

Answer (score 2):

After looking into syslog, I noticed that it's a segfault in geoip module

```
Aug 10 12:55:39 web kernel: [1183521.905522] nginx[30201]: segfault at 7fa773b7f2ce ip 00007fa772bc5478 sp 00007fffe4adc570 error 4 in libGeoIP.so.1.6.0[7fa772bbe000+2d000]
```

So, I bet it's caused either by geoip module or corrupted GeoIP.dat file. After looking into the file, I found that it's corrupted. Then I download the file again, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

A way to debug could be checking the environment for the GEOIP variables, e.g. in PHP look in the `$_SERVER` array, or try `getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE)`.

Make sure to define the variables in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`:

```
### SET GEOIP Variables ###
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
```

[source](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-geoip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16.04/)